# Bike choice wizard?

Tags: discussion

I don't see this (presumable)  FAQ anywhere onsite. Nor does Uncle Google help.

Is there a simple wizard anywhere that asks a few questions and recommends a bike?

Age, height, weight, spring to mind. Other fitness - e.g do you run, swim, etc & no seek a bike?

City? Country? Exercise? Commute? Budget?

You all know the FAQ because 1) it's every fourth question on this site and 2) you can't go to any gathering without getting "bike guy" questions

So, is there any way to obviate those questions and get a guesstimate. Yes, I know that there is no simple answer, but just something that fits the 80/20 rule ?

Comment: Sounds simple, isn't really. If there was, then google would be the best way to find it anyway?. NB this is meta, so it's not the main site, but even if it was moved across I think it would be closed for one of the 'quickly obsolete' reasons.

Comment: Concur - this isn't really a question about the bicycles.SE site but its also not about a bicycle.   I'm not sure where it should be, but the main site seems most appropriate.  Do you want it migrated ?

Comment: @Swifty which is why I did not ask on the main site :-)  I am active on a few sites (see profile), but on new sites I tend to run my first question past meta first, just in case.

Comment: I have closed this question because it is not about Bicycles SE. It would also be [off-topic](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the main site because it is seeking a service recommendation. It would, however, be a _great_ topic for [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect any such flowchart would be quite flat, with more of a questionaire look of "*if this, then that*"

- Do you want to go fast on the road ?   **Road bike** or **TT bike**
- Do you want to go fast on a track ?   **Track bike**
- Do you want to ride dirt/gravel roads?    **Gravel bike**
- Do you want to ride up tracks that would be hard to walk?   **Lightweight MTB**
- Do you want to ride down tracks that would be hard to walk?   **Downhill MTB**
- Do you want to do both the above?   **All-mountain MTB**
- Do you want to ride long distance on those tracks?   **Enduro MTB**
- Do you want to commute to work/school?  **Rigid/Hybrid flat bar commuter**, with mudguards
- Do you want to do stunts/tricks?   **BMX**

---

- Do you ride up hills? Consider a double or triple chainring
- Do you ride on the flat exclusively?  Consider a 1x single chainring

---

- Will you be riding in the rain?   Get a bike that can take mudguards/fenders
- Will you be riding at night?   Buy and fit lights.

---

- Do you have injuries?   Seek medical advice - a flow chart can't help you.
- Are you tall?  Get a taller frame
- Are you short?  Get a shorter frame
- Are you fat?  Get a frame and wheels rated for your weight.

It doesn't really produce any useful results - if you expected to feed in height/weight/location and have it suggest a specific brand/model of bike, then that would be something an individual manufacturer might produce to help differentiate their website.  But a brand-agnostic suggestor seems overly complex.

Comment: I'm not a MTB person - those lines are off the cuff and purely as examples.

Comment: Thanks, ***very** much. That certainly leads me to a decision. I am a programmer by trade, and if you can give any more detailed info then I can Open Source an app. I can, of course [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) for some of the basics, such as height of rider <-> size of frame, etc. I guess that that would cover the 80/20 case - after all, those who have an awareness of the arcane are unlikely to use a wizard ;-)  But, any detailed info, or links thereto, would be very, very welcome

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica sizing and bike fit are very personal.  While you could assume tall people need tall frames, there are long legs, long torsos, and potentially long arms.  Tall people often have one or two of those, so long legs need a large frame but combined with normal length arms means an average length top-tube.

Comment: I was under the impression that “enduro” mountain bikes get their name from a competition format where riders have to get back up the hill between runs, but the competition is timed on the downhill sections; and that enduro bikes aren’t necessarily the mtb equivalent of an endurance bike, but a step between Trail/allmtn and DH. That would suggest that the choice between a trail bike and an enduro bike, or even a relatively long travel XC bike, is less about distance and more about intended terrain. And as much as I love a good FD, many modern mtb frames cannot accept them, even for XC

Comment: @Pisco thank you for that - yeah I was using that as an example based on the name, probably glossed over too much.

Comment: I was only thinking about the 80/20 case. There are those, like me, who need this rule-of-thumb approximation, and those, like you, who do not. For us n00bs. "good enough" is ... well, good enough, and a software wizard would be somewhat helpful, absent a "bike guy" friend (visiting a dedicated bike shop would be extremely helpful; visiting the bike aisle as Costco would not).